# Como obter a data do primeiro e último dias da semana atual com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Preciso pegar a data do primeiro e último dias da semana atual. Por exemplo, estamos na semana do Natal, e eu gostaria que a função `primeiroDiaSemanaData()` retornasse `20/12/2020` e a função `ultimoDiaSemanaData()` retornasse `26/12/2020`.

Não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function primeiroDiaSemanaData() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = date.getDate();
    var dayOfTheWeek = date.getDay();
    var newDate = date.setDate(today - dayOfTheWeek + 7);

    var dataInicial = new Date(newDate);

    return dataInicial;
}

function ultimoDiaSemanaData() {
    var date = new Date();
    var today = date.getDate();
    var dayOfTheWeek = date.getDay();
    var newDate = date.setDate(today - (dayOfTheWeek || 7));

    var dataFinal = new Date(newDate);

    return dataFinal;
}
```

Comment: Tem que ser uma solução manual como voce está fazendo ou você aceita uso de alguma biblioteca pra ajudar na resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = new Date('2020-12-25T00:00:00');

// O primeiro dia é o dia do mês, menos o dia da semana
var primeiro = data.getDate() - data.getDay(); 
 
primeiroDia = new Date(data.setDate(primeiro)).toUTCString();
ultimoDia = new Date(data.setDate(data.getDate()+6)).toUTCString();

console.log(primeiroDia)
console.log(ultimoDia)
```

Comment: Obrigado @Rodrigo Zem!! Seu exemplo funcionou e o script ficou simples. :)

Answer (score 5):

Vou dar uma solução que faz o uso da biblioteca [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/). O uso desta meio que reduz o trabalho que teriamos escrevendo toda a lógica na mão, pois o código fica mais simplificado e fácil de entender.

Caso não seja possível uso de bibliotecas de terceiros para sua solução, apenas ignore minha resposta.

Vamos lá, sabendo que podemos obter a data atual, ou de uma data futura, usando `Date`, você pode importar o `date-fns` via *cdn*:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js">
</script>
```

<sub>Após importar via *cdn*, podemos usar `dateFns` no código.</sub>

Dentro deste, temos os métodos:

- `startOfWeek`: que retorna a data de começo da semana
- `endOfWeek`: que retorna a data de fim da semana

Ambos os métodos recebem a instância do objeto `Date`, e retonam o valores informados acima.

Vamos de exemplo:

```js
let date = new Date();

const inicioSemana = dateFns
  .startOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 0 })
  .toLocaleDateString('pt');
const fimSemana = dateFns
  .endOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 0 })
  .toLocaleDateString('pt');

console.log('Para a data: ', date.toLocaleDateString('pt'));
console.log('Inicio da semanda: ', inicioSemana);
console.log('Fim da semanda: ', fimSemana);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
```

Repare que:

- coloquei `toLocaleDateString('pt')` para formatar a data para o padrão que você informou.
- tem esse objeto `{ weekStartsOn: 0 }` onde o valor `0` representa o começo da semana, no caso, domingo. Se você mudar pra `1`, o começo da semana será segunda.

*O código funciona mesmo?*

Vamos testar para uma data futura, 29 de dezembro:

```js
let date = new Date();

date.setDate(29) // dia 29 de dezembro

const inicioSemana = dateFns
  .startOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 0 })
  .toLocaleDateString('pt');
const fimSemana = dateFns
  .endOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 0 })
  .toLocaleDateString('pt');

console.log('Para a data: ', date.toLocaleDateString('pt'));
console.log('Inicio da semanda: ', inicioSemana);
console.log('Fim da semanda: ', fimSemana);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
```

Agora vamo refatora para adaptar ao seu código:

```js
let date = new Date();

function primeiroDiaSemanaData(date) {
  const inicioSemana = dateFns
    .startOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 0 })
    .toLocaleDateString('pt');

  return inicioSemana;
}

function ultimoDiaSemanaData(date) {
  const fimSemana = dateFns
    .endOfWeek(date, { weekStartsOn: 0 })
    .toLocaleDateString('pt');

  return fimSemana;
}

console.log('Para a data: ', date.toLocaleDateString('pt'));
console.log('Inicio da semanda: ', primeiroDiaSemanaData(date));
console.log('Fim da semanda: ', ultimoDiaSemanaData(date));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
```

Comment: muito boa sua resposta, mas infelizmente ainda não posso usar bibliotecas no meu projeto, mas futuramente, se precisar usar, será muito interessante. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var dataAtual = new Date(); // obtem data atual
var primeiro = dataAtual.getDate() - dataAtual.getDay(); // Obtem primeiro dia da semana atual
var ultimo = primeiro + 6; // Primeiro dia da semana + 6

var primeiroDiaDaSemana = new Date(dataAtual.setDate(primeiro)).toUTCString();
var ultimoDiaDaSemana = new Date(dataAtual.setDate(ultimo)).toUTCString();

console.log(primeiroDiaDaSemana)
console.log(ultimoDiaDaSemana)
```

Comment: ops estava errado, eu tinha pegado de um exemplo em ingles e traduzido as variaveis, deixei essa escapar, mas o certo é "dataAtual" no lugar de "curr"

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda! Tem um bug na linha "var ultimo = primeiroDiaDaSemana + 6;" onde deveria ser "var ultimo = primeiro + 6;". Tirando esse bug, seu exemplo funcionou 100%. Obrigado :)

Comment: ah sim, corrigi aqui, é a mesma situação mesmo do curr